# Storing an Echo Command inside a Variable

Tags: php, html

I have programmed an eye exam and  I need to echo some stored SESSION variables which contain their results but they need to be inside another variable which I then print using HTML and even though I refresh the page those SESSION variable have their values stored and display that value again so it should only display those values after I have completed the exam

```
 $result_display = "<h1> Your Results For The Eye Exam Are:<br>
               Test 1 Left EYE:  '".$_SESSION['one_L']."' <br>
               Test 1 Right EYE: '".$_SESSION['one_R']."' <br>
               Test 2 Left  EYE: '".$_SESSION['two_L']."' <br>
               Test 2 Right EYE: '".$_SESSION['two_R']."' </h1>";
```

here is the variable that I then display later using HTML

```
 echo"<h1>'".$result_display."'</h1>";
```

What can I Do to prevent this from being displayed before the exam is even conducted.

Can I Use such a condition ?

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
    $content_instruction = $test_1L;
    $content_form = $forms_1L;
    $result_display = "";}
```

Comment: You could write an if that checks if the exam has been conducted?

Comment: Could you use a function/method instead of a variable?

Answer (score 1):

As @naruto said above, wrap the echo with an if:

So

```
echo"<h1>'".$result_display."'</h1>";
```

Becomes

```
if (isset($_SESSION['one_L'])
    && isset($_SESSION['one_R'])
    && isset($_SESSION['two_R'])
    && isset($_SESSION['two_R'])
) {
    $result_display = "<h1> Your Results For The Eye Exam Are:<br>
           Test 1 Left EYE:  '".$_SESSION['one_L']."' <br>
           Test 1 Right EYE: '".$_SESSION['one_R']."' <br>
           Test 2 Left  EYE: '".$_SESSION['two_L']."' <br>
           Test 2 Right EYE: '".$_SESSION['two_R']."' </h1>";
    echo "<h1>'".$result_display."'</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if $_SESSION['two_R'] is set at the end of the test, use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['two_R'])){

   echo $result_display;

}
```

Or replace the $_SESSION['two_R'] from the isset check with any variable that gets set after the exam completes.